# ref.once() not being called

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm trying to get the username by accessing a
data value saved as a child within the uid (as the parent):

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://mintio.firebaseio.com");

var authData = ref.getAuth();
var username = null;
ref.on("value" , function(snapshot){
    console.log("reading initiaized");
    var usernameSnap = snapshot.child(authData.uid).child("name");
    username = usernameSnap.val();
    console.log("username read");
});
```

but the username stays empty and the message is never being logged into the console... as if the once() function is never being called.
The authData object holds the correct uid ("google:107739486693148575362")
and the data looks like this:
[image]

EDIT:
These are my security rules:

```
{
    "rules": {
      "users": {
        "$uid": {
            ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
            ".write": "auth !== null && auth.uid == $uid" 
        }
      }
    }
}
```

If this isn't enough information the repo can be found here: https://Minzkraut@bitbucket.org/Minzkraut/mintio.git

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: How are you constructing your reference?

Comment: @DavidEast this part 'var ref = new Firebase("https://mintio.firebaseio.com");' ?

Comment: Can you update your code sample?

Comment: I can't see why your once() function won't fire. Can you try reproducing this in a JSBin?

Comment: @DavidEast ok, I'll try that.

Comment: @DavidEast i guess pasting it into the jsbin just like that doens't work at all: https://jsbin.com/ximezatizi/edit?html,js,console,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try to access you database, I get:

> Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.

So it seems like you have security rules that prevent the read from succeeding.

Most likely, you have a security that ensures each user can only access their own user data:

```
{ 
  "rules": {
    "$uid": {
      ".read": "auth.uid == $uid"
    }
  }
}
```

If you have security rules similar to the above, when executing this query:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://mintio.firebaseio.com");
ref.on("value" , function(snapshot){ ...
```

You are trying to read from the root of your database. The Firebase server checks this against your security rules and notes that you don't have read access to the root of the database. So it rejects the operation.

What you want is to access the user's data directly:

```
var ref = new Firebase("https://mintio.firebaseio.com");
ref.child(ref.getAuth().uid).on("value" , function(snapshot){ ...
```

With this last snippet, the read operation starts on the user's own data. The Firebase server checks against the rules and will see that `"auth.uid == $uid"` is true.

This is one of the two most common pitfalls with Firebase security rules:

- [Rules are not filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter)
- [Permissions cascade](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-cascade)

Comment: i made my code and rule changes according to your suggestion... it seems logic but the documentation didn't really tell me about that... unfortunately it still never enters this function. Not when I test locally nor when i deploy to firebase-hosting

Comment: I had to make quite some assumptions, because your question does not include your security rules nor did you mention getting an error message. Unless you update your question to contain a **minimal** complete verifiable example, there's not much more I can help you with.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I didn't expect the rules to play such a big role... i will update my question to contain the necessary information.

Comment: Given what is now in your question, my answer explains why it won't work: you need read access on the level where you try to read. Please study http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve carefully and provide an minimal, complete reproduction.